# How to change visual appearance of only the page numbers in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am using the following MWE to merge multiple pdfs. As different pdfs come with their own page numbers, I am adding another serial page number for the entire merged document with a distinctive look. For instance, I have used a box with black borders and yellow background to place the new page numbers here. Now, I want that distinct formatting of the page numbers to also appear in the TOC. How do I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[includefoot,bottom=3pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\thepage}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\title{Documents for Metric 1.3.1}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Logo.png}\\
                \hrulefill
            \end{center}
            \maketitle  
            \hrulefill
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}, width=\paperwidth, addtotoc={1,section,1,Gender Policy,}]{Gender Policy.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}, width=\paperwidth, addtotoc={1,section,1,Sexual Harassment Redressal Policy,}]{SH.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}, width=\paperwidth, addtotoc={1,section,1,Students' Welfare Policy,}]{SW.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}, width=\paperwidth, addtotoc={1,section,1,Syllabus for Value Education,}]{VE Syllabus.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to redefine the way the page numbers are displayed in the Table of Contents (TOC). Here's a minimal working example (MWE) using the tocloft package to customize the TOC appearance and the fancyhdr package to add custom headers/footers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Define custom page number style
\newcommand{\mypagenum}[1]{\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\textbf{#1}}}

% Redefine the way page numbers are displayed in the TOC
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1.5} % Adjust dot separation
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\mypagenum}

% Custom header and footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\mypagenum{\thepage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First Section}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{document1.pdf}
\clearpage

\section{Second Section}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{document2.pdf}
\clearpage

\section{Third Section}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{document3.pdf}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now, I am out of station and don't have access to a system. Will let you know after applying to my code in a few days.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. However, your code is not working if the page number in the `toc` has more than one character.

Comment: can you go with this?